# How to dynamically add and remove CSS file via Wordpress Customizer

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have added a section in the customizer for users to choose whichever theme they prefer

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVEiz.png)

I want to load **green.css** in the head when **green theme** is selected and **blue.css** when **blue theme** is selected.

I have JS codes for that but I don't know where to add them and how to trigger that JS code when selection is made via the customizer section.